# Sketch arc shape with rounded corners

Tags: vector, sketch-app

I'm using the following layer structure to create an arc shape in Sketch:

[image]

I'm going to create several lengths of arc that are an arbitrary length around the circle (e.g. one at 45º, one at 90º, one at 135º, and so on).

What I'd like to do is reliably and accurately round the corners of each arc shape that I create -- like this, but an actual perfect half circle, not poorly hand-drawn path arcs.

[image]

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another method. Might be cleaner

Keep your shape as a stroke with help of scissor tool.
[image]

 1. Use the "scissors" tool on your yellow stroke circle. That way you keep the shape as a stroke and can move them around. To add the scissor tool in your toolbar, right click on the toolbar and click "Customize toolbar". Then drag the scissor tool in your toolbar. Super handy for vectors.

2.Go to **Borders** settings.

3.Check the new joints and ends options available.
[image: Observe Ends & Joints options]

4. Choose the middle ends button. Viola! Perfectly round stroke ends.

   [image: Perfectly Round Stroke ends.]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was rather simple: add a circle inside the mask group on either end.

[image]

While I didn't end up with a compound shape, the rounds look very nice this way.

[image]

Comment: I imagine a lot of folks would attempt this method and it would work for previous versions of Sketch or Illustrator. Definitely would work for pixel based programs like Photoshop since there aren't too many vector options available. The best approach for this issue though is to get familiar with stroke ends options now that it's available. It makes the mock process a lot faster too.

Comment: Agreed. I changed the accepted answer